# SVG clipping "as you go"

Tags: svg, clipping, clip-path

In the Windows API and the PostScript language you can setup clipping at any point along the way.

An unreal but simple example:

a) I draw a circle.

b) Then I set a clipping rectangle.

c) Then I draw another circle.

d) Then I remove the clipping.

I can't find a way of doing that with SVG. I'm probably missing something, and I can't find an example which could help me.

Do all the clipping rectangles windows I want to use in the file have to be setup at the beginning?

I've tried this:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.1" width="2678.000" height="1600.000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    viewBox="0.000000 0.000000 2678.000000 1600.000000">
    <g clip-path="EEE">
        <clipPath id="EEE"> <rect x="40" y="40" width="1000" height="1000"/> </clipPath>
        <polyline style="stroke:#FF5F42;stroke-width:4;fill:none;"  points="0,0  2000,1500  "/>
        <polyline style="stroke:#FF5F42;stroke-width:4;fill:none;"  points="0,0  500,500  "/>
        <polyline style="stroke:#00FF00;stroke-width:4;fill:none;"  points="0,0  250,250  "/>
        <text x="284" y="1365" style="text-anchor:start;dominant-baseline:hanging;font-size:36.0px;"> Flux 5300.00  lm</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

...however I can still see the text which should have been clipped out. It is at 1365 and the clipping rectangle ends at 1040...

Comment: set the clipping on a group <g>, put the shapes you want clipped in the group element.

Comment: Thanks Robert, can you give me an tiny simple example of a clipping inside a group? I can't find any clear examples....

Comment: <g clip-path="whatever"><rect/><rect/></g>

Comment: Has clip-path "whatever" been previously defined? If so that is what I'm trying to avoid. At the time of writing the start of the file I don't know all the clipping required. Till I get to the end...

Comment: doesn't need to be. you can put the clipPath element after the clip-path reference. Try it and see.

Comment: Robert, I've changed my original question and think I've followed you advice, but no joy...

Comment: That's the wrong syntax for clip-path: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Comment: You mean in the original post or in the answer to myself?

Comment: In the question, it's right in the answer. When I wrote the comment there was no answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ooooops. Think I've got there.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.1" width="2678.000" height="1600.000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    viewBox="0.000000 0.000000 2678.000000 1600.000000">
    <defs>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#EEE)">
        <clipPath id="EEE">
            <rect x="0" y="140" width="1000" height="800"/> 
        </clipPath>
        <polyline style="stroke:#FF5F42;stroke-width:4;fill:none;"  points="0,0  2000,1500  "/>
        <polyline style="stroke:#FF5F42;stroke-width:4;fill:none;"  points="0,0  500,500  "/>
        <polyline style="stroke:#00FF00;stroke-width:4;fill:none;"  points="0,0  150,1250  "/>
        <text x="284" y="1365" style="text-anchor:start;dominant-baseline:hanging;font-size:36.0px;"> Flux 5300.00  lm</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

My first error was thinking I had to define something before using it. See how I use EEE before I define it above...

My second error was not understanding how to use "url(...)" agh.

Thanks to Robert Logson for nudging me along in the right direction.